# How to merge two JsValues?

Tags: json, scala

I have the following:

```
abstract class Super(val m0: Member) {
  def toJson: JsValue = Json.toJson(Map(("m0", m0.toJson)))
}

class Sub(m0: Member, m1: Member) extends Super(m0) {
  def toJson: JsValue = ??? // should use super.toJson
}
```

How would Sub.toJson be defined such that it can reuse Super.toJson and produces:

```
// assuming m0.toJson is "member0" and m1.toJson is "member1"
{
  "m0": "member0",
  "m1": "member1"
}
```

Comment: You can merge two `JsObject` with the `++` operator. Maybe you can use this.

Comment: Your types dont make sense. is it supposed to be `class Sub(m0: Member, m1: Member) extends Super(m0)` ?

Comment: I'm close to understanding what you're trying to ask, but not quite close enough.  Please try to clean up the question.

Answer (score 1):

This assumes that super.toJson returns a JsObject because we don't know the key for the member otherwise.

```
class Sub(m0: Member, m1: Member) extends Super(m0){
  def toJson: JsValue = {
    (super.toJson, Json.toJson(Map(("m1", m1.toJson)))) match {
      case (mm0: JsObject, mm1: JsObject) => mm0 ++ mm1
      case _ => JsNull
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't reuse the superclass's toJson function.